# How to make a 'Select' component as required in Material UI (React JS)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, material-ui

I want to display like an error with red color unless there is a selected option.
Is there any way to do it.

Comment: there are many of ways to do that. show your code sample first. then we can help you.

Comment: <div className="form-group">
                                               
                                                <Select className="mdc-listdata" data={countries} label={'País'}
                                                        selected_value={this.countryChange.bind(this)} id={'sb_country'}
                                                /> </div>

Comment: @ObsidianAge could you please tell me a way :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For setting a required Select field with Material UI, you can do:

```
class SimpleSelect extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    selected: null,
    hasError: false
  }

  handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({ selected: value });
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(state => ({ hasError: !state.selected }));
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { selected, hasError } = this.state;

    return (
      <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
        <FormControl className={classes.formControl} error={hasError}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor="name">
            Name
          </InputLabel>
          <Select
            name="name"
            value={selected}
            onChange={event => this.handleChange(event.target.value)}
            input={<Input id="name" />}
          >
            <MenuItem value="hai">Hai</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="olivier">Olivier</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="kevin">Kevin</MenuItem>
          </Select>
          {hasError && <FormHelperText>This is required!</FormHelperText>}
        </FormControl>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

### Working Demo on CodeSandBox

[image: Edit soanswer51605798]

Answer (score 3):

Material UI has other types of Select(native) also where you can just use plain HTML required attribute to mark the element as required.

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl} required>
  <InputLabel htmlFor="name">Name</InputLabel>
  <Select
    native
    required
    value={this.state.name}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    inputProps={{
      name: 'name',
      id: 'name'
    }}
  >
    <option value="" />
    <option value={"lala"}>lala</option>
    <option value={"lolo"}>lolo</option>
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

P.S. https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/#native-select

Comment: It also works with non-native Select, as it is placed in the FormControl tag.

Comment: When I place the "required" in the FormControl I get the " * " so it looks required. But when I submit the form, it doesn't actually force the user to fill out the field like with TextField.

Comment: Add `<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}></form>` will solve the issue.  @alsky

Answer (score 0):

**The `required` prop only works when you wrap your elements inside a `<form>` element, and you used the `submit` event to submit the form.**

- this is not related to react, this is pure HTML.

In MUI v5 (2022), it works like this:

```
const handleSubmit = (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault()
  // ...
}
return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
   <Select required value={val} onChange={handleChange} required>
    <MenuItem value="yes">Yes</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="no">No</MenuItem>
   </Select>
   <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
  </form>
)
```

As you can see, it works the same way you think it should work, so what your code should probably be similar to this.
**But the required prop only works when you wrap your elements inside a  element, and you used the `submit` event to submit the form.**

And if you're using `<FormControl>`, but the required prop on both elements:

```js
<FormControl required>
  <Select required>
    // ...
</FormControl>
```