# Material Ui - Add required attribute to a TextField in "select" mode

Tags: reactjs, validation, material-ui

I am trying to make "required" a TextField in select mode.
I tried to add `required` prop like in this snippet, but this does not block the submit event if I haven't select anything. Although it adds the '*' to the label.

Please check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6jxvvq9463)

```js
<TextField
  id="select-currency"
  select
  label="Select"
  value={this.state.currency}
  onChange={this.handleChange("currency")}
  required
>
  {currencies.map(option => (
    <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
      {option.label}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</TextField>
```

UPDATE: (Clarification really)
I am talking about html5 validation. In the sandbox example there are Select and Text fields, setting the text field as required will block the submit event and displays a native html5 error saying "this field is required", this is not the case if the field is "select".

Comment: First of all Welcome!

Check this, it might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605481/how-to-make-a-select-component-as-required-in-material-ui-react-js

Comment: Thank you for this example but I am talking about html5 validation. I will clarify the question.

Comment: It's not native html select. You shouldn't be expecting it to work that way.

Comment: As pointed out by @Vincente below, this is now [implemented](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/20402) in material-ui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Material Ui provides another component [Native Select](https://material-ui.com/demos/selects/) to handle this kind of native validation.

Please check this example

[image: Edit Material demo]

Answer (score 1):

It was recently implemented in material ui. If you upgrade `@material-ui/core` to version 4.11.0 it will work https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/20402

Answer (score -2):

It's not field responsibility to control form behavoiur. It's parent-child relation and top-down data passing.

Form (component) provides current value to component (validity information, change handler) to field component. Field displays content using styles and elements depending on props (`*` when required, error border etc) but it's form' role to decide about value/validity/submiting.

Comment: Thank you but I am talking about html5 validation. In the sandbox example there are Select and Text fields, setting the text field as required will block the submit event and displays a native html5 error saying "this field is required", this is not the case if the field is "select".

Comment: It's not 'native html select' then don't expect native html5 behaviour (browser managed).

Comment: From what I know, these material-ui components are using native html input underneath, this is why it works with the normal text field.

Comment: In the chrome element inspector, I tried to add directly a required attribute to the html input inside the Select component and it worked fine. I think that this "required" prop I add to the text field does not reach the html input underneath in the "select" mode.

Comment: MUI components is a kind of superset to html fields, not all of them are intended to have the same behaviour. Sometime native error signaling collide with expectations. Report a bug/create an issue on MUI github - they'll fix it or explain why it's not implemented.

Comment: Thank you... I created an issue [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12749) and will post the answer here when I have it